# commenting restriction

Tags: ruby, comments, newline, indentation, ruby-1.9

In ruby 1.9, conditions on where to end a line was relaxed, so that we can now start a line with a period showing a method call. This is convenient when we have chained and non-chained methods mixed up, and want to show where the next non-chained one starts. Without this new feature, the best we could do was probably to use indentation:

```
method1(args1).
  method2(args2).
  method3(args3)
method4(args4).
  method5(args5).
  method6(args6)
```

or insert a blank line. But this was inconvenient because we have to pay attention to the indentation, and at the same time, not forget to put a period after every method call but the last one in the chain. Because of this, I created so many bugs either having an extra or missing period. With the new feature, we can do it much nicer as:

```
method1(args1)
.method2(args2)
.method3(args3)
method4(args4)
.method5(args5)
.method6(args6)
```

where the period visually functions as indented bullets.

The problem is that, when you want to insert comments before a line starting with a period, it returns an error.

```
method1(args1)
# method2 does blah blah
.method2(args2)
# method3 then does foo foo
.method3(args3)
method4(args4)
# method5 does blah blah
.method5(args5)
# method6 then does bar bar
.method6(args6)

# => error
```

or

```
method1(args1)
 # method2 does blah blah
.method2(args2)
 # method3 then does foo foo
.method3(args3)
method4(args4)
 # method5 does blah blah
.method5(args5)
 # method6 then does bar bar
.method6(args6)

# => error
```

It seems that, `"#...."` is not simply dropped off, but is interacting with the code in some way. What is happening? What is the exact restriction here? When the periods were at the end of a line, this did not happen.

```
method1(args1).
  # method2 does blah blah
  method2(args2).
  # method3 then does foo foo
  method3(args3)
method4(args4).
  # method5 does blah blah
  method5(args5).
  # method6 then does bar bar
  method6(args6)

  # => no error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexical parser is probably "looser" in that it will ignore a single newline and whitespace immediately preceding a dot. It probably does not allow for multiple newlines. This splits chained statements up into an incoherent mess, and it becomes much more complicated to handle without false positives. That all said…

**If you have to add inline comments, it's probably an inappropriate place for terse, chained statements.**

Comment: I often have a chain of one-liners, each doing a particular task, and it makes sense to comment line-by-line.

Comment: And it's still against convention. You shouldn't have to comment one every line — the code should speak for itself. In cases where it doesn't some inline comments are helpful. Especially in regards to chaining, you can break those statements up into a list of calls and append very short line-ending comments on any that are unclear (if needed). Nobody wants to read a sentence-long comment and then the word-long code it belongs to. We get it.

Comment: It's the other way around. The one-liner may have a block, or have a complicated regex. The comment can be simple phrases. In addition, I often test a few alternatives for a one-liner within the chains, and need to comment out the alternatives not under test